# How create a JOB with EJB 3.0 inside JBOSS 4.3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, jobs

How I can create a job that runs every 6 seconds and the work begins automatically when performing the deploy of the application?

Currently I have this class that use timers, but the process does not start automatically when start the deploy.

All this with EJB 3.0 in JBoss 4.3 and the EAR without a WAR, only EJBs

```
@Stateless
public class MyJobBean implements MyJob {
private static final long EJECUTION_INTERVAL=6000;
@Resource
private TimerService ts;
@PostConstruct // This not work in deploy, only when somebody calls the EJB
public void init() { 
    System.out.println("Post Constructor Method init() Invoked"); 
    ts.createTimer(EJECUTION_INTERVAL, null);
}
@Timeout // Fired by the timer 
public void myJOBProcess(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("the job was invoked");

    ts.createTimer(EJECUTION_INTERVAL, null); //create another future ejecution
}
@PreDestroy
public void tidyUp() {
    System.out.println("Canceling scheduled Timers");
    for (Object obj : ts.getTimers()) {
        Timer timer = (Timer)obj;
        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("Timer Canceled");
    }   
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss you could use MBeans which are defined by annotating a service with `@Service`. If there is a `public void start()` method this will be called when the application is started.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet listeners or load-on-startup servlets were the only javaee-portable way to autorun some code on deploy until EJB 3.1 with @Schedule annotation.